# Animating driving down a road

Tags: javascript, css, css-transforms

I want to animate a road so that it looks like you are driving on it. I got this far: https://jsfiddle.net/v6k2gy9m/1/

What I did is that I translate and scale each part so that it looks like you where driving.

My problem is that the images that are parts of the road do overlap during the animation in that wobbly manner. I have no Idea why that is happening.

I think the problem lies in the following line but I am not sure why. Here I try to translate all tiles by delta but I translate the farther tiles by less using the scale factor `scaleF` But it seems to be not 100% correct. What am I missing?

```
translate = translate - delta * scaleF;
```